# How to use if else before .then() .catch() in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, if-statement, vue-component

I'm creating app in Vue.js. I have two similar methods:

```
    editTool() { 
      return ToolService.editTool(this.id, this.editedItem)
        .then((response) => {
          this.$refs.dialogInfo.setSuccess(response);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          this.$refs.dialogInfo.setError(error);
        })
        .finally(() => {
          this.$emit("completed");
        });
    },

    newTool() {
      return ToolService.addTool(this.editedItem)
        .then((response) => {
          this.$refs.dialogInfo.setSuccess(response);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          this.$refs.dialogInfo.setError(error);
        })
        .finally(() => {
          this.$emit("completed");
        });
    },
```

They only differ in the value in return, rest is the same. I want to turn these two methods into one. I tried this way:

```
    newMethod() {
      if (this.edit) return ToolService.editTool(this.id, this.editedItem);
      else
        return ToolService.addTool(this.editedItem)
          .then((response) => {
            this.$refs.dialogInfo.setSuccess(response);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            this.$refs.dialogInfo.setError(error);
          })
          .finally(() => {
            this.$emit("completed");
          });
    },
```

But it doesn't work correct. How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try in the following way.

```js
editTool() {
    return ToolService.editTool(this.id, this.editedItem)
  },

  newTool() {
    return ToolService.addTool(this.editedItem)
  },

  newMethod() {
    let method = this.newTool;
    if (this.edit) method = this.editTool;
    return method().then((response) => {
        this.$refs.dialogInfo.setSuccess(response);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.$refs.dialogInfo.setError(error);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        this.$emit("completed");
      });
  }
```